# Finding $P(X+Y \geq 0.5)$ given $f(x,y) = x - y + 1$ for $0 \leq x, y \leq 1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

For the bivariate density function (not necessarily independent)
 $$f(x,y) = x - y + 1$$ for $$0 \leq x, y \leq 1$$

I am trying to find $\Pr(X+Y \geq 0.5)$.

I integrated $y$ across $0.5-x$ to $1$ and then integrating that from $0$ to $1$ $$\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{0.5-x}(x-y+1) \,dy\,dx$$

But this seems to be wrong when I go through the calculation. I don't know what I could have done wrong here?

Comment: To take both information $y\ge \frac12-x$ and $y\ge 0$ into account, the integral should be $\int_0^1 \int_{\max(1/2-x,0)}^1(x-y+1)\,dy\,dx=\int_0^{1/2}\int_{1/2-x}^1(x-y+1)\,dy\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^1 (x-y+1)\,dy\,dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this plot of the region help?

[image]

Comment: Not really, I know your trying to show me the surface I'm meant to be integrating but I don't really know how to interpret that, sorry I'm new to double integration.

Comment: OH.... Okay, I see...... Thanks!